# unity how to control camera view using a single joystick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Does any one know how to control the camera view with only a single joystick? Currently im using a joystick from the switch.
Heres my current code.

```
 public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float speed = 1.0f;
Camera cameraMovement;

void Update () 
{    

    float xRot = speed * Input.GetAxis("JoyStickX");
    float yRot = speed * Input.GetAxis("JoyStickY");

    transform.Rotate(xRot, yRot, 0.0f);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the editor, create an empty game object called "Pivot"
- Make your camera a child of Pivot.
- Move the camera away from Pivot, whatever distance you need.
- Now attach a script to Pivot.

Something like this :

```
 void Update(){
     float speed = 3.0f;
     float xRot = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     float yRot = speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     transform.Rotate(xRot, yRot, 0.0f);
  }
```

- Assign your camera to the camera var in the script attached to Pivot
- Now you do the messing around of the rotation