# Rotate camera with right joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a 3D game and I want my camera to rotate by joystick. My game has a first person controller that have already the movement controlled by left joystick and I want my main camera to rotate with the right joystick.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController cc;
    public Joystick joystick;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float xInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        float zInput = joystick.Vertical;
        cc.Move(new Vector3(xInput, 0, zInput));

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unity how to control camera view using a single joystick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294739/unity-how-to-control-camera-view-using-a-single-joystick)

Comment: no , I want 2 joysticks

Comment: You want left joystick for translation and right for rotation? Keep your current code for the left joystick and use that post to make the right joystick rotate the camera.